# Does it makes sense to use Spark for descriptive analytics with a relational non-sharded data store (e.g. MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, bigdata

As the title says, our data lives in a managed MySQL database without sharding or clustering.

Are the architectural benefits of Spark (in-memory parallel processing, ability to join across multiple data sets) applicable in this case, or does MySQL become the bottleneck from an IO perspective, making Spark benefits void ?

Answer (score -1):

sounds like plain old SQL will work better in your case - unless you are planning to move to more diverse backends and/or migrate out of MySQL

Comment: I kept my question intentionally short and focused, but yes, in future we will not only use other backends (e.g. object stores, NoSQL) while applying more advanced analysis methods (streaming, predictive analytics, factorization). So Spark is considered an investment in the future, and my question was aimed at determining how big the penalty is that we would have to pay short term by relying on a single platform. Of course, one can always build multiple stacks or migrate to a different stack when scale becomes a problem. But that has other complex implications (funding, agility etc.)

Comment: The overhead depends on how much data you'd push to Spark itself vs. how much you'd invest in the query that you make to MySQL. the more logic you'd put in the queries the less use you'd make of spark. Again, unless you have specific plans in a near future it sounds like wasted effort

Comment: Understood, but based on my understanding, the analytic query and join capabilities within MySQL are somewhat limited anyway, so the majority of the processing logic (aggregates) would live in Spark with MySQL merely providing the data. Similar to loading a csv file from S3 into Spark where S3 doesn’t perform any processing logic either. So my understanding is that I/O would be determined/impacted by MySQL but query performance would be entirely independent of MySQL once the data has been loaded in-memory within the Spark cluster.

Comment: "o my understanding is that I/O would be determined/impacted by MySQL but query performance would be entirely independent of MySQL once the data has been loaded in-memory within the Spark cluster. " - exactly